# Network shows 'device not managed' in Ubuntu 11.04

Tags: ubuntu, networking, static-ip

I have Ubuntu 11.04 and set up a static IP address in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

When I try to restart Ubuntu, suddenly in the task bar it shows a message

> device not managed

How can I re-enable my network?

Comment: Have you already did some research? For example: [network manager says “device not managed”](http://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed) Maybe include your `interfaces` file in your post and show us the output of `ifconfig`.

Comment: TARA:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/71159/network-manager-says-device-not-managed